# Magento 1.8 - Same website different url

Tags: magento-1.8, magento-1, multistore

Is it possible to show the same products, pages, etc. on a different url?

The current situation is we have a Dutch website and we want to have a Belgium website. Both country's speak the same language, so basically we can show the same website for the Belgian people as for the Dutch people.

[image]

Current result: example.com/be/ redirects to example.com/nl/

Expected result: /be/ shows same website as /nl/ but payment methods, shipping costs, etc. are different.

Comment: You should consider setting up one store view that (if needed reflect both or more languages, i.e. /be-nl and) modify your payment methods so they allow a per-country based definition like it is possible with shipping methods already. Reason being, you'll create a huge mess in terms of SEO having a huge amount of duplicate content when you have to different path to basically the same shop.

Comment: I understand your concern about the SEO part, but we can mask that with a cannonical url. The problem is that magento does not allow to change shipping and payment settings on storeview level. So we can't create a new storeview under the same website because it willl use the shipping and payment settings of the website level and not the storeview level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your requirements, you have **two** ways to do that:

- create two stores with their views.
- create two websites.

If you want to just change the language, payement, shipping, for each instance, and you keep the same catalog for the both, the same url with language code:`domaine/nl`, `domaine/be` you can use different stores and view (**the paiement, shipping methods are configurable per storeview**)

If you want to do that and then have different **urls** for each language: `domaine.nl`, `domaine.be`, you have to use the websites way.

Comment: Shipping costs are not configurable on storeview level...

Comment: Yes, natively you can enable disable the shipping method and not the costs but you can available this feature in `system.xml`, `<show_in_store>1</show_in_store>` BUT I advise you to use a websites solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using different payment and shipping method , You need to create two different website , from magento admin and configure accordingly .